# function not defined window on load

Tags: javascript, function

What is wrong with this code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

            window.onload = function()
            {
                function addText() 
                {
                        var el = document.createElement('p');
                        el.innerHTML = 'This is test';
                        document.getElementById('b').appendChild(el);
                }

            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body id="b">
        <a href="#" onclick="addText();">c</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

I get addText is not defined when I click on anchor. When I put addText function outside windowl.onload anonymous function it works

Comment: yea it would work if you take it out of onload, in your case the addText is only visible inside of onload

Answer (score 0):

I think the function you are creating is a closure on an anonymous function on window.onload, so the main scope doesn't see it.

I don't know JS directly, but in functional languages like Clojure you can give a name to a function for self reference by it but it remains an anonimous function if you don't bind it to a name. When you put outside the function the self referring name is also the bind name for the function.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining a function within another function and then trying to call that inner function.

Remove the declaration of addText() out of the window.onload function.

Answer (score 0):

If you define a function (X) (using a function declaration) inside another function (Y) then X will be scoped to Y and will not be accessible outside it (unless you copy it to a global variable).

I can't see any reason for defining that function `onload`, so just get rid of the onload wrapper for it.

Answer (score 0):

`addText` is only visible in the scope where it was created. Make it into an anonymous function which you assign to `window.addText` and it will work as expected:

```
window.addText = function() { ...
```